# Sed command with regular expression and replace

Tags: regex, shell, unix, sed

I am new to sed command and regular expressions.

Could anyone help me to explain the below command

```
 echo "FIXTEST_XYZ             23040/tcp       # 127.0.0.1:23040" | sed -n 's/^FIXTEST_\([A-Za-z0-9]\+\)\s\+\([0-9]\+\)\/tcp\s\+#\s*\([A-Za-z0-9.]\+\):\([0-9]\+\)\s*/\1 \2 \3 \4/p'
```

Thank you for your help !!

Comment: This might help: `man sed` and [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: TLDR; but you should give more details on what input the command operates.

Comment: Updated the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [explainshell](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=echo%20%22FIXTEST_XYZ%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2023040%2Ftcp%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20127.0.0.1%3A23040%22%20%7C%20sed%20-n%20%27s%2F%5EFIXTEST_%5C%28%5BA-Za-z0-9%5D%5C%2B%5C%29%5Cs%5C%2B%5C%28%5B0-9%5D%5C%2B%5C%29%5C%2Ftcp%5Cs%5C%2B%23%5Cs*%5C%28%5BA-Za-z0-9.%5D%5C%2B%5C%29%3A%5C%28%5B0-9%5D%5C%2B%5C%29%5Cs*%2F%5C1%20%5C2%20%5C3%20%5C4%2Fp%27) for command explaination.

Check [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rY0IEY/1/) for regex explanation:

```
^FIXTEST_([A-Za-z0-9]+)\s+([0-9]+)\/tcp\s+#\s*([A-Za-z0-9.]+):([0-9]+)\s*

FIXTEST_ matches the characters FIXTEST_ literally (case sensitive)
1st Capturing Group ([A-Za-z0-9]+)
    Match a single character present in the list below [A-Za-z0-9]+
    + Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
    A-Z a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)
    a-z a single character in the range between a (index 97) and z (index 122) (case sensitive)
    0-9 a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)
\s+ matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
2nd Capturing Group ([0-9]+)
    Match a single character present in the list below [0-9]+
    + Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
    0-9 a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)
\/ matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
tcp matches the characters tcp literally (case sensitive)
\s+ matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
# matches the character # literally (case sensitive)
\s* matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
3rd Capturing Group ([A-Za-z0-9.]+)
: matches the character : literally (case sensitive)
4th Capturing Group ([0-9]+)
\s* matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
Global pattern flags
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
```

1st Capturing Group matches: `XYZ`

2nd Capturing Group matches: `23040`

3rd Capturing Group matches: `127.0.0.1`

4th Capturing Group matches: `23040`

Bash standard output: `XYZ 23040 127.0.0.1 23040`

Comment: Thank you Ben for your explanation. I understood it now.